# Как получить актуальный индекс символа в NSLayoutManager

Tags: ios, swift

Пытаюсь получить актуальную позицию выбранного в `NSTextContainer` символа (по тапу) следующим образом:

```
func handleTouch(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
   var location = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self)
   let startPoint = self.layoutManager.locationForGlyphAtIndex(0)
   location = CGPoint(x: location.x - startPoint.x, y: location.y - startPoint.y)
   var fraction: CGFloat = 0
   let index = self.layoutManager.glyphIndexForPoint(location, inTextContainer: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceThroughGlyph: &fraction)
}
```

И это работает как и должно до тех пор, пока в строке не встретится перенос строки сделанный установкой атрибута стиля:

```
NSParagraphStyle.hyphenationFactor = 2
```

Каждый перенос с дефисом сдвигает искомый мною символ на одну позицию. Как я могу получить актуальный индекс, если задан перенос строки с установкой дефисов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте с его аналогом  [characterIndexForPoint(_:inTextContainer:fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSLayoutManager_Class_TextKit/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSLayoutManager/characterIndexForPoint:inTextContainer:fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints:)

Похожий вопрос на [стеке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349725/character-index-at-touch-point-for-uilabel)

Comment: Благодарю. Заменил метод и всё работает как надо)
let index = layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(location, inTextContainer: self.textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)